# ionic searchbar filter is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am developing an ionic app. I want show the list of countries in search bar when using keyword. I am fetching the data from api.
It is working for

```
[
  'Amsterdam',
  'Berlin',
  'Bueno Aires',
  'Madrid',
  'Paris'
];
```

But itis not working for the json array.

```
[{
    "name": "Afghanistan",
    "topLevelDomain": [".af"],
    "languages": ["ps", "uz", "tk"],
    "translations": {
        "de": "Afghanistan",
        "es": "Afganistán",
        "fr": "Afghanistan",
        "ja": "アフガニスタン",
        "it": "Afghanistan"
    },
    "relevance": "0"
}, {
    "name": "Åland Islands",
    "topLevelDomain": [".ax"],
    "languages": ["sv"],
    "translations": {
        "de": "Åland",
        "es": "Alandia",
        "fr": "Åland",
        "ja": "オーランド諸島",
        "it": "Isole Aland"
    },
    "relevance": "0"
}]
```

The error is showing as

`TypeError:_this.items.filter is not a function`

Below shown as the code.

```
export class ModalPage{
    resp;
    items: array<any>;
    showList;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public rest: RestProvider) {

    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad ModalPage');
    }

    getItems(ev: any){
         let val = ev.target.value;
         /**   call api ***/

            this.rest.selectCountryFn(val)
                .then(data => {
                this.items = data;
                this.items = JSON.stringify(data);
                console.log("json :"+this.items);   //json is shown as correct

                if (val && val.trim() != '') {

                    // Filter the items
                    this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
                    return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
                });


            } else {

                    // hide the results when the query is empty
                    this.showList = false;
                }

            });

            /*** api call end  ****/
        }
}
```

**html code**

```
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
   <ion-list *ngIf="showList">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="select(item.name)">
      {{ item.name }}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Please help me. I have tried different methods. But i didn't get the result..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. I convert the json data to array. I used `items: any;` for declaration. And i used

```
const usersJson: any[] = Array.of(this.items);
```

for converting json to array. For adding the list after filter. I used

```
this.items = <any[]>JSON.parse(this.items);
```

And the final code is,

```
export class ModalPage{
    resp;
    items: any;
    showList;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public rest: RestProvider) {

    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad ModalPage');
    }

    getItems(ev: any){
         let val = ev.target.value;
         /**   call api ***/

            this.rest.selectCountryFn(val)
                .then(data => {
                this.items = data;

                const usersJson: any[] = Array.of(this.items);



                if (val && val.trim() != '') {

                    // Filter the items
                    this.items = usersJson.filter((item) => {
                    return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
                });

                this.items = <any[]>JSON.parse(this.items);

                this.showList = true;


            } else {

                    // hide the results when the query is empty
                    this.showList = false;
                }

            });

            /*** api call end  ****/
        }
}
```

Comment: Is each array item in the data from the server response really a `string`? It's not an parsed object with properties? What data type does `data` from the response have? Did you set `selectCountryFn` to have a return type of an array of something? You're doing a lot of casting and parsing and it's not clear why and I can only guess without a functioning example, but I image it's because `data` is being returned as `any` from `selectCountryFn`.

Comment: I am using casting and parsing because when i put different data instead of any. It is showing errors. In the service it coming as string. It is successfully displaying in console. I tried different ways. Finally i got the answer on this way.

Answer (score 2):

The issue should be with the following line specifically:

```
this.items = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Once this is executed, `this.items` is no longer a valid JavaScript array that would have [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method available, as it becomes a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) with `JSON.stringify()`. You wouldn't need to do `JSON.stringify()` at this moment anyway, you can always `JSON.stringify()` the entire data after filtering before sending to your API.

```
getItems(ev: any) {
  let val = ev.target.value;
  /**   call api ***/

  this.rest.selectCountryFn(val)
    .then(data => {
      this.items = data;
      console.log("json :"+this.items);   //json is shown as correct

      if (val && val.trim() != '') {
        // Filter the items
        this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
          return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        });
      } else {
        // hide the results when the query is empty
        this.showList = false;
      }
    });
    /*** api call end  ****/
}
```

With that being removed, you will need to update your `filter()` statement to do something like stringifying each item to use with `indexOf()` or targeting specific object properties for comparison:

```
this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
  return JSON.stringify(d).toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1;
});
```

The last thing is your definition of class property `items: array<any>;` is incorrect. It would need to be `items: any[];` or `items: Array<any>;` with a capital "A". That being said, I'd recommend to always try to provide a default value, in this case an empty array `items: any[] = [];`, but even better would be creating an interface/class to represent your data structure:

```
export interface Country {
  name: string;
  topLevelDomain: string[];
  languages: string[];
  translations: { [key: string]: string };
  relevance: string;
}

items: Country[] = [];
```

I made an Ionic [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-azmyuf) to show this functionality in action at a basic level.

Below is the basic JavaScript of this functionality:

```js
const data = [{
  "name": "Afghanistan",
  "topLevelDomain": [".af"],
  "languages": ["ps", "uz", "tk"],
  "translations": {
    "de": "Afghanistan",
    "es": "Afganistán",
    "fr": "Afghanistan",
    "ja": "アフガニスタン",
    "it": "Afghanistan"
  },
  "relevance": "0"
}, {
  "name": "Åland Islands",
  "topLevelDomain": [".ax"],
  "languages": ["sv"],
  "translations": {
    "de": "Åland",
    "es": "Alandia",
    "fr": "Åland",
    "ja": "オーランド諸島",
    "it": "Isole Aland"
  },
  "relevance": "0"
}];

const val = 'AF';

const items = data.filter(d => {
  return JSON.stringify(d).toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1;
});

console.log(items);
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: If that error is happening, it is because you may be doing JSON.stringify() on the data from the API or the data isn't an array at some moment. Are you absolutely sure you removed any `JSON.stringify()` surrounding the array, or at the moment when the `.filter()` is being executed it is an actual array and not a string? I can recreate the exact error because of `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: I have declared the variable item as  " items: any; " is there any problem in declaration?

Comment: If it&#39;s any array, you&#39;d at minimum want type `any[]` or `Array<any>` with a capital "A", but that being said even better would be a type to reflect the structure of the data.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander Staroselsky . Finally i got the answer. Thank u for support.